# select ID so you can create a dynamic query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to php and phpmyadmin and I have a problem with a web application that I am making. 
I know how to enter items in the DB and how to displays them. But now I have to do both.

I have to make sure they select a name from the option tag that comes from the db. I need the ID of this name so I can create a new query

/* Hier I get the data*/

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" name="SelecteerKlas" method="get" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" >

      <select>
        <?php 
        if (!empty($data)) {

          foreach ( $data as $var ) 
          {
            $k_id=$var['k_id'];
            echo "<option name='klasID' value='$k_id'>",$var['k_leerjaar'],$var['k_naam'],"</option>";
          }
        }else{
          $feedback= '<p class="alert alert-danger">Momenteel staan er nog geen klassen in de database!</p>';
          echo $feedback;
        }

      ?>
      </select>

      <input name="btnSelectKlas" type="submit" id="btnSelectKlas" value="Selecteer klas" >
      </form>
```

But I don' know how to proceed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have syntax errors in concate string  in below line:

```
echo "<option name='klasID' value='$k_id'>",$var['k_leerjaar'],$var['k_naam'],"</option>";
```

and you also need to echo your message outside of the form if array is empty.

Try like this:

```
 <?php 
            if (!empty($data)) {
    ?>
    <form class="form-signin" role="form" name="SelecteerKlas" method="get" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" >

          <select name="my_select">
            <?php 


              foreach ( $data as $var ) 
              {
                $k_id=$var['k_id'];
                echo "<option name='klasID' value='$k_id'>".$var['k_leerjaar'].$var['k_naam']."</option>";
              }
            }
          ?>
          </select>

          <input name="btnSelectKlas" type="submit" id="btnSelectKlas" value="Selecteer klas" >
          </form>
    <?php
    else{
              $feedback= '<p class="alert alert-danger">Momenteel staan er nog geen klassen in de database!</p>';
              echo $feedback;
            }
    ?>
```

you need check if form is submit after submitting the form you can get select value by `$_REQUEST['my_select']`